# How to create a subtraction formula in R that is conditional?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, formula

I want to create a variable which has as value the distance between two other variables that are already there. I know I have to calculate the difference between the two variables to get the distance. Now the problem is that I need to make sure, that the first value is bigger than the second one:

```
Distance = ( X (if X bigger than Y, otherwise Y) – Y ( if Y smaller than X, otherwise X)
```

Does anyone know how to translate the conditions into an R-formula?

I have tried a normal R formula for a subtraction:

```
coilp5 <- mutate(coilp5, dist. = X - Y)
```

but then I get values I cannot work with, if the X is smaller than the Y

Comment: you can use the absolute value `abs(x - y)`

Comment: Mael, smart, KISS it smart.  EmStaLo, as a newbie, suggest always first consider base R solutions before rushing to the complexities of the Tidyverse.

Comment: @Maël thank you very much! I have been trying to upvote your answer, but I haven't figured out how...

Comment: It's not an answer here, it's just a comment. If @Maël posts it as an answer, it'll appear below these comments, and it'll have up/down arrows (for voting) and a checkmark that should be selected to mark that answer as "accepted".